# How to calculate the Euclidean distance in a canny image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, euclidean-distance, canny-operator

I have a black line and purple lines. I want to calculate the distance between each purple pixel points in the canny image and the closest black line in the most efficient and fastest way. How can I do it? Is there any opencv-python function?

[image: Actual image]

[image: Canny Image]

Comment: You mean you want to know, for every single individual purple pixel, the distance to the nearest black pixel?

Comment: Yes you got it right. I will do this on the canny image.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is close but haven't checked it too much yet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load input image
im = cv2.imread('PBv6H.png')

# DEBUG Get list of all unique colours in image
# np.unique(im.reshape((-1,3)),axis=0)

# Find purple pixels
purplepixels = np.where(np.all(im==[164,73,163],axis=-1))

# Make black and white image with only the black pixels from original
bw = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, bw = cv2.threshold(bw,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# DEBUG cv2.imwrite('bw.png', bw)

# Now calculate the distance from every pixel to the nearest black one
# Every pixel in "dst" image has a brightness equal to its distance to nearest black pixel 
dst = cv2.distanceTransform(bw, cv2.DIST_L2, cv2.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)

# Print out the distance to the nearest black pixel for each purple pixel
for y,x in zip(purplepixels[0], purplepixels[1]):
   print(f'[{y},{x}]: {dst[y,x]}')
```

This is the distance transform image - the brighter a pixel is, the further it is from a black pixel:

[image]

Here is the thresholded black and white image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. You've made me very happy. I appreciate. I wonder if we can find out coordinate of the nearest black pixel?

Comment: You should be able to change `cv2.distanceTransform()` to `dst, labels = cv2.distanceTransformWithLabels(bw, cv2.DIST_L2, cv2.DIST_MASK_PRECISE, labelType=cv2.DIST_LABEL_PIXEL)`

Comment: Actually, this was the reason I asked you to clarify in the comments that you just wanted the distance (rather than the coordinates of the nearest pixel). If you actually want the coordinates of the nearest pixel, you may be better off with **SciPy** function  `scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt()`

Comment: I write this function and I solve it. Thank you so much.`edt, inds = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(bw, return_indices=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Consider a "distance transform" on a picture of one of the line types. Then, for any point of the other line type, look up the distance instantly.

Or turn your lines into polygons/polylines. That's an enormous reduction in data and turns your problem into a geometry problem.

Comment: Yes I think like that but sorry, I am new on image processing so I need extra information or an example to do it.

Comment: please look for "opencv distance transform". you will find a little tutorial on this in the official documentation.