# how to find the nearest coordinate between two lines on canny image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, euclidean-distance

come from this post
[How to calculate the Euclidean distance in a canny image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142431/how-to-calculate-the-euclidean-distance-in-a-canny-image/71934337#71934337)
I wonder how to find coordinate of the nearest black pixel?

Comment: The answer to that question is literally in the link you provided...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the Euclidean distance in a canny image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142431/how-to-calculate-the-euclidean-distance-in-a-canny-image)

Comment: its run well i got all purpel line coordinate and the distance, but i just dont have any idea to print out the coordinate of the nearest black pixel. i am realy new to this

Comment: in the post said the solution was using,  `edt, inds = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(bw, return_indices=True)`. right here i dont know how to get the nearest black pixel

Comment: @UAT were you able to find a solution?